# How to detect webcam?

Tags: hardware, drivers, webcam

I installed Cheese, but my webcam doesn't work. What should I do?

This is the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 0483:2016 SGS Thomson Microelectronics Fingerprint Reader
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 044e:3012 Alps Electric Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 044e:3013 Alps Electric Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 044e:3010 Alps Electric Co., Ltd Bluetooth Adapter
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 044e:3011 Alps Electric Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ca:1839 Ricoh Co., Ltd Visual Communication Camera VGP-VCC6 [R5U870]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Could you please use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com). The data you pasted is all mixed up. Also, have you checked if your webcam is compatible? You can read all documentation regarding webcams on ubuntu [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam). It would also be nice if you could post your webcam's model and manufacturer.

Comment: @sebikul: it's really perfectly fine to paste data to askubuntu.com, without using external services. Of course it should be formatted (four spaces before text, as DoR edited). Even if you paste something lengthy, askubuntu.com will format it meaningfully.

Comment: @Olli: I know you can paste data directly to Askubuntu, but before the edit, it was all in one line, and it was really hard to understand

Comment: @sebikul: therefore, it's better to edit it, instead of using external service, which can be down etc. You can also suggest edits to posts (and then moderators will accept those).

Comment: @Olli: I never thought that, great suggestion!!

Answer (score 2):

I googled your webcam model and chip, there are a few solutions, but i cant say they WILL work, but they are worth the try.

### Solution 1

The first one, and the more reliable one, is to add and install the packages available in the following [ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Er5u87x-loader/+archive/ppa). They will install a firmware loader so other apps can recognize your webcam. (remember to reboot after install)

### Solution 2

Download the following [file](http://www.palmix.org/download/r5u870_k2.6.30_i386.tar.bz2)
Uncompress it and execute:

`cd r5u870`

`make`

`sudo make install`

`sudo modprobe r5u870`

in that order

### Solution 3/4

This is only to be done if you have a great experience building kernel modules. It can be found [here](http://www.arakhne.org/ricoh/index.html)

Another user who managed to build his own kernel module, instructions [here](http://ubuntu-ky.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1681233)

---

I hope one of the solutions i mentioned above solve your problem. I recommend you starting with the first one.

Comment: ya it help me alot and not i got ma webcam working .......thnaks guys!!!!!

Comment: Guys i m in trouble again. Above instruction helped me earlier but now i have updated my system to Ubuntu 11.10 and followed the same instruction again but yet my webcam is no working..Help me!!!!!